# open file in new tab

Tags: android-studio

Does Android Studio have the option of opening a referenced file in a new tab (like Xcode's <kbd>Alt</kbd>-`click` feature)?

If not, is there a way of creating this?

Comment: Does `Cmd + B` works for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open current editor tab in new window

```
Shift+F4
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I couldn't find a way of "Duplicating Tabs". But there are two workarounds that might help:

1) Right click on a tab title and choose either `Split Vertically` or `Split Horizontally`. This can be done multiple times!

2) If for some reason you don't want to see the files side by side, there's another hack (works for me on Mac): First, right click on a tab title and choose either `Split Vertically` or `Split Horizontally`. Now, drag the extra tab (by its title) on to the title bar of Android Studio => the tab will pop out into a new window!

Hope this helps!